# Simulate error handling with promises on router.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am trying to save Sensor values to my mongodb database. I am using promise to do proper error handling. I am using `then()` and `catch()` but I guess I am not doing it right. I send a group Id so it checks if the group id exists then only it stores sensor information. 
Here is my code.

```
router.post('/data/:group_id', function(req,res,next){
    var group_id = req.params.group_id;
    User.find({group_id : group_id}).then(function(user){
        var object_id = user[0]._id;
        var datas = req.body;
        var data = new Data({
           user : object_id,
            value: datas.value,
            valueString : datas.valueString,
            sensorStatus : datas.sensorStatus,
            timeStamp : new Date().toJSON()
        });
        data.save().then(function(data){
            res.send('Data Saved');
        });
    }).catch(function(e){
        if(e.code === undefined){
            res.send('Group id does not exist');
        }else{
            res.send(e);
        }
    });
});
```

if I send a group Id that does not exist it does say Group id does not exist, but if I send a wrong json data for saving my sensor information, there is no error but my postman-app which I am using to send information gets stuck. Here is a error I purposely generated with a valid group ID.

I am new to this so need to understand how promise handles the error for first if the group_id cannot be found and second if the sensor json information is wrong.

Sent to `http://localhost:3000/api/data/3`

```
{
    "value1" : "79" ,
    "valueString" : "Small data",
     "sensorStatus" : "false"
}
```

Extra information User and Datas model. Note( Dint add the require and export part)

```
var schema = new Schema({
    group_id : {type : Number, required: true},
    password : {type : String, default: null},
    project : {type : String , default : null}
});
var schema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    value :{type : Number , required : true} ,
    valueString : {type : String, required : true},
    sensorStatus : {type : Boolean , default : 0},
    timeStamp  : {type :String , required : true}
});
```

Comment: @chridam yes sure!

Comment: Off-topic: I would suggest changing the `timeStamp` data type to `Date` and do the casting to string in the application layer since Mongo works best with dates stored using the date type. The issue may be related to this line `timeStamp : new Date().toJSON()`, not too sure as I haven't tested it.

Comment: @chridam I am not so confident in this but as I can see it looks like when I give a wrong json file, I am thinking that my error handling is just wrong. Even if the timestamp does cause error, it should catch it and show it right? Hope I made sense

Comment: The promise returned from `data.save()` doesn't have an error handler, I think you need to return the promise in that case, then add another `then()` on the first promise which will send the response, hope you catch my drift.

Comment: @chridam so should I do it like this ? 
if(user == undefined || null){ throw new Error('Unable to find group id ');}
So catch will only take care of the storing data party

Comment: No, I meant something like http://pastebin.com/bV5Chd5E

Comment: @chridam did not work, now if i enter invalid group id that doesnt exist it doesnt show error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, you're falling to a common pitfall: Don't nest `.then()` clauses, instead, return Promises and chain:

Don't do

```
foo().then(() => {
  bar().then(() => {
    baz();
  }
}
```

Return the Promise from inside of the `.then()` and chain, like so:

```
foo()
  .then(() => { return bar(); })
  .then(() => { return baz(); });
```

Or the shorter version

```
foo()
  .then(() => bar())
  .then(() => baz());
```

---

In your case:

```
router.post('/data/:group_id', function(req,res,next){
  var group_id = req.params.group_id;
  User.find({group_id : group_id})
    .then(function(user){
      // bla bla bla
      return data.save();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      return res.send('Data Saved');
    });
    .catch(function(e){
      if(e.code === undefined){
          res.send('Group id does not exist');
      }else{
          res.send(e);
      }
    });
});
```

As a common rule: Always **return** or **throw** from a `.then()` handler.

Comment: Thanks alot! It works, but there is a small problem, when the group id is wrong the (e) returns `{}` I am not sure how to even tell the user that the group id is wrong. Is there anyway to catch that error properly?

Comment: @MasnadNihit - isn't that what the `if(e.code === undefined){` is doing?

Comment: @JaromandaX for some reason an empty array is not equalling to undefined.

Comment: you stated *"when the group id is wrong the (e) returns {}"* ... well if `e` is `{}`  then `e.code` is not an empty array `[]` I can assure you